# WPF Application is interrupted when entering edit mode of nested datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am using MVVM and trying to use a nested datagrid to display my data. my data has two classes `Step` and `Line` as model, they are sort of hierachical.

CS:

```
    public class Step
    {
        public int StepID { get; set; }
        public string StepName { get; set; }
        public int RecipeID { get; set; }
        public int Run_Order { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Line> Lines { get; set; }
    }
    public class Line
    {
        public int LineID { get; set; }
        public string CommandName { get; set; }
        public string CommandParameter { get; set; }
    }
```

My ViewModel:

```
class RecipeMainPageViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
        private ObservableCollection<Step> stepsList;
        public ObservableCollection<Step> StepsList
        {
            get { return stepsList; }
            set
            {
                stepsList = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("StepsList");
            }
        }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding StepsList}" Visibility="{Binding DataGridVisibility}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="No." Binding="{Binding Run_Order}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding StepName}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Command" Binding="{Binding CommandName}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="CommandParameter" Binding="{Binding CommandParameter}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>                            
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

I want to display them by a nested datagrid and both of the datagrids can be editable and save back.

**The problem is :**

when I use my mouse to click and enter editting mode of the datagrid, the application is interrupted with the ArgumentOutOfRangeException. And it says "Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)." However when I use just my keybord to move between cells and enter editting mode, everything's fine. I check the stack trace of the exception. It seems that the app stops at `System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.BringIndexIntoView(Int32 index)`
I guess something happens in this method.

the detailed information of the exception is below:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
  HResult=0x80131502
  Message=指定的参数已超出有效值的范围。
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
   在 System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.BringIndexIntoView(Int32 index)
   在 System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridCellsPresenter.ScrollCellIntoView(Int32 index)
   在 System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.ScrollCellIntoView(ItemInfo info, DataGridColumn column)
   在 System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnCurrentCellChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   在 System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   在 System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   在 System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
```

**What I have tried:**

1. Use `RowDetailsTemplate` to nest the child datagrid, like the xaml code above.
2. Use `DataGridTemplateColumn` to nest the child datagrid.
3. Use the Syncfusion SfDataGrid.
   1 and 2 don't work and they throw the same exception. 3 works fine, but Syncfusion requires a community license(though I have one). Is there any way to solve this by using native WPF toolkits or open source third part toolkits.

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to ***Debug >> Windows >> Exception Settings***.   In the search box on the top right, Type "ArgumentOutOfRange".  You will see a checkbox for `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` appear on the left.  Check that box.  Now run the application in *Debug* mode and do the thing that makes the exception happen.  You'll stop exactly where it happens.

Comment: @Joe, the exception says that "Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)." And the stack trace stops at `System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.BringIndexIntoView(Int32 index)`. I guess something wrong with the indexes of the datagrids